# How to add textarea tag as input element in sweet alert using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sweetalert

I don't understand how to add a `textarea` type 
in `sweet` alert.
Similar to **`type: "input"`**

```
$('#saveBtn).click(function(){
    swal({   
        title: "Enter your Name!",  
        text: "your name:",  
        type: "input",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        closeOnConfirm: false, 
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        animation: "slide-from-top",   
        inputPlaceholder: "Write something" }, 
        function(inputValue){  
             if (inputValue === false) 
                 return false;    
             if (inputValue === "") {
                swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");  
                return false
                }
            swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success"); 
         });
});
```

This works fine. But if I use  **`type: "textarea"`** instead of **`type: "input"`**

This gives error like this:

```
sweetalert.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: logStr is not defined
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show what you've coded...

Comment: $('#saveBtn,#createNewBtn').click(function(){
  swal({   
   title: "Enter your Name!",  
   text: "your name:",  
   type: "input",   
   showCancelButton: true,   
   closeOnConfirm: false, 
   showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
   animation: "slide-from-top",   
   inputPlaceholder: "Write something" }, 
   function(inputValue){  
     if (inputValue === false) 
      return false;    
     if (inputValue === "") {
      swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");  
      return false
      }
    swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success"); 
    });
 });

Comment: @Guruprasad. Could you please tell me where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `textarea` as a type since the sweetalert does not support that.

> The type of the modal. SweetAlert comes with 4 built-in types which will show a corresponding icon animation: "warning", "error", "success" and "info". You can also set it as **"input"** to get a prompt modal. It can either be put in the object under the key "type" or passed as the third parameter of the function.(*[Taken from here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)*)

---

Instead you can use html markup with `text` option by setting `html` option true. But in this way you can't get value inside the textarea as callback variable. For that give an id to the textarea and get value using that.

```js
swal({
  title: "Enter your Name!",
  text: "<textarea id='text'></textarea>",
  // --------------^-- define html element with id
  html: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
}, function(inputValue) {
  if (inputValue === false) return false;
  if (inputValue === "") {
    swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
    return false
  }
  // get value using textarea id
  var val = document.getElementById('text').value;
  swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + val, "success");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: good idea, worked with me, one point: I don't think we will need the inputValue anymore, and no need to check, because it will never get a value.

Answer (score 18):

The original SweetAlert plugin is currently unsupported and you probably won't see textarea functionality in it. I created [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) which has the `textarea` functionlaity:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Input something',
  input: 'textarea'
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(result.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

[Textarea example in SweetAlert2 documentation ↗](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-textarea)

The transition from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2 is easy, here's the [migration guide](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input: "textarea"` instead of `input: "text"`
If you are using sweetalert2 or want to use sweetalert2, you can include these:

```js
function openSwal(){
  swal({
      title: "Are you sure you want write somethin' in text area?",
      input: "textarea",
      inputPlaceholder: "Enter somethinn",
      showCancelButton: true,
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
      confirmButtonText: "Submit ",
      inputValidator: function(value) { // validates your input
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          if (value != '' && value != null) {
            // document.getElementById('closeComment').value = value; // assign this to other elements in your form
            swal("Success!", "You comment: " + value, "success");
            // call other functions or do an AJAX call or sumbit your form
          }
          else {
            reject('Please enter a valid text');
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.5/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.0.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.0.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<button id="something" onclick="openSwal();">Open Sweet Alert</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sweetalert1` , `html: true` is not supported any more (so the accepted answer doesn't work anymore). instead you can get the value of text area manually with:

```
value = document.querySelector(".swal-content__textarea").value
```

Full code:

```
swal({
  text: "Enter some text :",
  content: { element: "textarea" },
  buttons: "Next"
}).then((value) => {
  if (!value) throw null;
  value = document.querySelector(".swal-content__textarea").value;
  alert("you entered: " + value);
});
```

[Run it on codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/VwaMYxY?editors=1010)

Also you can use `sweetalert2` instead if it's possible (see other answers).